# how to define this line of code in python in order to pass mypy checking

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I have such define in my python code:

```
options = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str)))
options['modem1']['ByCost'] = ...
options['modem1']['ByCarrier'] = ...
options['modem1']['BySimSignal'] = ...
options['modem1']['SwitchBackByTimer'] = ...
```

And it fails during my pre-commit/mypy checking, for the message that :

```
Need type annotation for 'options'
```

Since I don't see anything wrong with this code, so is there any work around that I can have it passed the mypy checking for this line ?

Btw, I am looking for alternative ways, other than setup this  in my code :

```
disable_error_codes with error code var-annotated
```

Thanks a lot !

Jack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Python 3.9+, [thanks to PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/), you can use `defaultdict` itself for type annotations, making this simple, if somewhat redundant/verbose (see bottom of answer for 3.9+-only solution that's a little less redundant/verbose, but can't be backported to 3.8 and earlier as easily):

```
from collections import defaultdict

options: defaultdict[str, defaultdict[str, defaultdict[str, str]]] = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str)))
```

Note that this assumes you actually have a three level `defaultdict`; your code is only going down two levels, so you'll get a checking error if you do:

```
options['modem1']['ByCost'] = 'abc'
```

because you really needed one more level of `str` keys:

```
options['modem1']['ByCost']['xyz'] = 'abc'
```

If you actually wanted two layers of `defaultdict`, trim it back to just:

```
options: defaultdict[str, defaultdict[str,str]] = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str))

options['modem1']['ByCost'] = 'abc'
```

If you're on Python 3.8 or earlier, replace the annotation using `defaultdict` with the `typing.DefaultDict` annotation, making it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import DefaultDict

options: DefaultDict[str, DefaultDict[str, DefaultDict[str, str]]] = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str)))
# Or if only two levels:
options: DefaultDict[str, DefaultDict[str, str]] = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str))
```

---

### Less redundant solution

Note: The 3.9 usage allows you to both annotate *and* use the annotated type, so as a 3.9+ only solution, you could do (showing two layer case for simplicity):

```
options = defaultdict[str, defaultdict[str,str]](lambda: defaultdict(str))
```

and not need to explicitly provide the annotation on `options` itself, as the top-level `defaultdict` is already annotated, implicitly annotating the variable it's assigned to.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It does solve my issue.

Comment: Just want to say thank you one more time. You have saved my plenty of time to have this  issue  resolved.  Thanks a lot.